# Group by query in MySQL ignoring the values inside brackets

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, group-by

I have a SQL query with groupby clause
the query looks like this:

```
SELECT
    products.product_name AS product_name,
    contracts_balance.contract_prod AS contract_prod, 
     SUM( contracts.opt_one_firm + contracts.opt_two_firm + contracts.opt_three_firm +contracts.opt_four_firm +contracts.opt_five_firm +contracts.opt_six_firm)
     AS total_open_balance
FROM
    (
        (
            contracts_balance
        LEFT JOIN products ON
            (
                (
                    contracts_balance.product_id_fk = products.product_id
                )
            )
        )
    LEFT JOIN supplier ON
        (
            (
                products.supplier_id_fk = supplier.supplier_id
            )
        )

         LEFT JOIN contracts ON
        (
            (
                contracts_balance.contract_id_fk = contracts.contract_id
            )
        )
    )
GROUP BY
    products.product_name ,  products.pack_size
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

**In the group by query I want the query to group by names ignoring the text inside brackets ()
So, It should return only 8 rows.**

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `substring_index()`:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(p.product_name, ' (', 1) AS product_name,
       cb.contract_prod AS contract_prod, 
       SUM( c.opt_one_firm + c.opt_two_firm + c.opt_three_firm + c.opt_four_firm + c.opt_five_firm + contracts.opt_six_firm) AS total_open_balance
FROM contracts_balance cb LEFT JOIN
     products p
     ON cb.product_id_fk = p.product_id LEFT JOIN
     supplier s
     ON p.supplier_id_fk = s.supplier_id LEFT JOIN
     contracts c
     ON cb.contract_id_fk = c.contract_id
GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(p.product_name, ' (', 1), cb.contract_prod;
```

Notes:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and read.
- The unaggregated columns in the `SELECT` should match the `GROUP BY` keys.  I don't understand why `cb.contract_prod` is in the `SELECT`, but not the `GROUP BY` and why `p.pack_size` is in the `GROUP BY` but not the `SELECT`.
- All those parentheses and white space just makes the query look more complicated than it is.

It is also irregular to use `LEFT JOIN`s in a query and to aggregate by a column that is not in the first table -- because it would have `NULL` values on non-matching rows.  I suspect you want `products` as the first table reference in the `FROM`.